# Mysql JOIN with 25million rows

Tags: mysql, performance, join, percona, query-performance

Recently I got stucked with a table where its grown to +25million and I have got a query that's doing a JOIN on it. The query take 2.5hours to execute even though I got Good 96GB RAM and RAID10 with BBU config.

TableA has 958090  records
TablesB has 25Million Records.

The query join is simple.

```
select tableA.col1, tablesA.col2, tablesA.directory, tableB.col1, tableB.col2
from tableA left join tableB ON tableA.col1=tableB.col1 AND tablesA.col2=tableB.col2
where tablesA.col2='123'
OTHER BY tablesA.directory desc;


tablesA.directory is VARCHAR(950);
INDEX ON tablesA.col2
INDEX ON tableB.col1 and tableB.col2
```

Please help me how to gain performance in this scenario.

Comment: Add indexes on (both tables) on `(col2, col1)`.

Comment: When you ask questions at this site, it's better if you add the tables descriptions (for mysql, the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`)

Comment: For queries performance, the `EXPLAIN` output as well.

Comment: I'm just curious about getting to 25 million rows in a table. :|

Answer (score 0):

Try adding index on combincation of `tableB (col2, ,col1)` because selection is happening on `col2`. This should work.